# A regular expression for matching a group followed by a specific character

Tags: regex

So I need to match the following:

```
1.2.
3.4.5.
5.6.7.10
```

`((\d+)\.(\d+)\.((\d+)\.)*)` will do fine for the very first line, but the problem is: there could be many lines: could be one or more than one.

`\n` will only appear if there are more than one lines.

In string version, I get it like this: `"1.2.\n3.4.5.\n1.2."`

So my issue is: if there is only one line, `\n` needs not to be at the end, but if there are more than one lines, `\n` needs be there at the end for each line except the very last.

Comment: There is a closing parenthesis missing `((\d+)\.(\d+)\.((\d+)\.)*` where should it be?  Or should the first one not be there?

Comment: Your regex doesn't match the last line fully ? you want to match full line or not ?

Comment: Please, add more examples that should match and that shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the pattern I suggest:

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?(?:\n\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?)*$
```

### Demo

Here is a brief explanation of the pattern:

```
^                   from the start of the string
\d+                 match a number
(?:\.\d+)*          followed by dot, and another number, zero or more times
\.?                 followed by an optional trailing dot
(?:\n               followed by a newline
\d+(?:\.\d+)*\.?)*  and another path sequence, zero or more times
$                   end of the string
```

Comment: It matches more than what's required. It would match `1.`, and `1.\n1.\n1.`.

Comment: @ArslanAli Yes, and this in fact is suggested by your own sample data.

Answer (score 2):

You might check if there is a newline at the end using a positive lookahead `(?=.*\n)`:

```
(?=.*\n)(\d+)\.(\d+)\.((\d+)\.)*
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UYApgH/1)

**Edit**

You could use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) to either match when on the next line there is the same pattern following, or match the pattern when not followed by a newline.

```
^(?:\d+\.\d+\.(?:\d+\.)*(?=.*\n\d+\.\d+\.)|\d+\.\d+\.(?:\d+\.)*(?!.*\n))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UxurH2/1/)

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d+\.\d+\.` Match 2 times a digit and a dot
  - `(?:\d+\.)*` Repeat 0+ times matching 1+ digits and a dot
  - `(?=.*\n\d+\.\d+\.)` Positive lookahead, assert what follows a a newline starting with the pattern
  - `|` Or
  - `\d+\.\d+\.` Match 2 times a digit and a dot
  - `(?:\d+\.)*` Repeat 0+ times matching 1+ digits and a dot
  - `*(?!.*\n)` Negative lookahead, assert what follows is not a newline
- `)` Close non capturing group

Comment: It doesn't match `1.2.`. If there is only one line, there won't be any `\n`.

Comment: @ArslanAli Would this be a better match? [demo 3 lines](https://regex101.com/r/UxurH2/1) and [demo 1 line](https://regex101.com/r/oNbKGZ/1)

Answer (score 0):

`(\d+\.*)+\n*` will match the text you provided. If you need to make sure the final line also ends with a `.` then `(\d+\.)+\n*` will work.

Comment: This regular expression also matches these kinds of strings `1...2...3...`.

Comment: @ElChiniNet, that's true. Here's a modified version that won't match multiple `.`'s in a row: `((\d+\.?)+\n?)+`

Comment: Hi, the issue with this second one is that it will match with something similar to `0123456789`.

Answer (score 0):

Most programming languages offer the `m` flag. Which is the *multiline* modifier. Enabling this would let `$` match at the end of lines and end of string.

The solution below only appends the `$` to your current regex and sets the `m` flag. This may vary depending on your programming language.

```js
var text = "1.2.\n3.4.5.\n1.2.\n12.34.56.78.123.\nthis 1.2. shouldn't hit",
    regex = /((\d+)\.(\d+)\.((\d+)\.)*)$/gm,
    match;


while (match = regex.exec(text)) {
  console.log(match);
}
```

You could simplify the regex to `/(\d+\.){2,}$/gm`, then split the full match based on the dot character to get all the different numbers. I've given a JavaScript example below, but getting a substring and splitting a string are pretty basic operations in most languages.

```js
var text = "1.2.\n3.4.5.\n1.2.\n12.34.56.78.123.\nthis 1.2. shouldn't hit",
    regex = /(\d+\.){2,}$/gm;

/* Slice is used to drop the dot at the end, otherwise resulting in
 * an empty string on split.
 *
 *     "1.2.3.".split(".")   //=> ["1", "2", "3", ""]
 *     "1.2.3.".slice(0, -1) //=> "1.2.3"
 *     "1.2.3".split(".")    //=> ["1", "2", "3"]
 */
console.log(
  text.match(regex)
      .map(match => match.slice(0, -1).split("."))
);
```

For more info about regex flags/modifiers have a look at: [Regular Expression Reference: Mode Modifiers](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refmodifiers.html)